# Using kubernets ingress controller to set x-forwarded-prefix to the first segment of the path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am running multiple instances of my http based application and I need to use an ingress controller to route to the correct instance based on the first segment of the path, but I also need to set that first segment in the x-forwarded-prefix path (so my application and set the correct values on subsequent calls), e.g. with the following config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    cert-manager.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "my-cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: persistent
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: sha1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by: "$pod"
  #  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: "<how to set this per path>"

spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /tenant1(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tenant1lb
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /tenant2(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: tenant2lb
            port:
              number: 80
    host: myservice.com
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - myservice.com
      secretName: frontend-prod-tls
```

What I'm struggling with is how to set this line `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: "<how to set this per path>"` to be dynamic, is there a way?

e.g. `https://myservice.com/tenant1` will route to `tenant1lb` and set `x-forwarded-prefix` to `tenant1`